# Importing local settings to codeception.yml

Tags: codeception

Is there mechanism to import local settings to codeception.yml configuration file?

Our developers have their own databases and maybe some other environment specific settings for the testing, so these settings shouldn't be pushed to GIT. Normally we solve this problem by having two configuration files, where other one is global & in GIT. Another, local one is merged in some way or another to global one and ignored by the git. What I like to achieve would be following structure:

- codeception.yml - global settings
- codeception.local.yml - local settings witch would be merged to global settings e.g. by the import

There is a include property for config files, but it seems to deal with complete testing suites.

Answer (score 6):

Yes actually.  I can't find anything the manual about it, so I dug through the source code and it looks like it reads both codeception.yml and codeception.dist.yml files.

I tested it out it looks like codeception.dist.yml is your global config, and codeception.yml is what you should use for your local and put into .gitignore. Same goes for the suite.yml files.  acceptance.suite.dist.yml is the global that gets overwritten by acceptance.suite.yml, etc etc.

Comment: There's this in the manual: http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Configuration Maybe you could add it to your answer.